# Upload multiple files with FormData using AngularJS and Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, input-type-file

I want to upload multiple files using angular js, for this I am using FormData() .

**Here is my form fields**

```
    <input name="profileImage" type="file" class="upload"
    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().LoadFileData(this.files)" accept="image/*">

 <input name="avatarImage" type="file" class="upload"
    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().LoadFileData(this.files)" accept="image/*">

    <input name="Id" type="text" ng-model="user.Id" />
<input name="Name" type="text" ng-model="user.Name" />
```

**Here is my Asp.Net MVC controller**

```
public ActionResult AddUser(string user, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    // parse user into User
}
```

**and the angular controller**

```
.controller('formController',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
        Id: 0,
        Name: ""
    };
    $scope.files = [];

    $scope.LoadFileData = function(files) {
        $scope.files = files;
    };

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http({
            url: "/Home/AddUser",
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": undefined },
            transformRequest: function(data) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("user", angular.toJson(data.user));
                for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                    formData.append("files[" + i + "]", data.files[i]);
                }
               return formData;

            },
            data: { user: $scope.user, files: $scope.files }
        })
        .success(function(response) {   });
    };
});
```

Problem is that I want to upload more than one image one for profile and the other for avatar . When I upload both only the second one shows up which override the previous one . I tried to push $scope.files.push(files) but it gives null.Need help what I am missing there.

Comment: why do you have name="file" on input fields remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `LoadFileData` function

```
$scope.LoadFileData = function (files) {
        $scope.files.push(files[0]);
    };
```

`files` returns a Filelist object and actual file object is at index 0.

Comment: Bro how to identity the image for profile and avatar this gives an array of two images?

Comment: instead of files array use two different names when sending formData

Comment: This not work avatarImage: $scope.files[0],profileImage:$scope.files[1]

Comment: How to use two different names when sending formData?

Comment: i am about to update my answer you just handle it , create a viewmodel that contains id,name,profileImage,AvatarImage .

Comment: But you can shared your way I want to know that I have made 2 loadData functions then append that to formData for both profile and avatar