# Upload Multiple Image using multiple file control in asp.net mvc 4.0 (angular js)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, file-upload

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express with Framework 4.5 MVC.

I am also using Angular Js for the first time.

I have a view page that contains the multiple browse (file) button that will be use for upload single image by selecting each of them individually with my form data.

[image]

The problem is that by using submit button I am not able to get the images but  I got the form data.

I want to get the images with the form data using Angular js.

I have already referred below posts but not getting the solution:

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018270/multiple-file-upload-control-in-angular-js-and-web-api-2-larger-byte-array-retur)

[LINK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160662/upload-multiple-files-with-formdata-using-angularjs-and-asp-net-mvc)

Please anyone help me to solve out this problem, would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an excerpt from your `form` source or better yet a jsfiddle/plunker/etc demonstrating the issue

Comment: I don't know how to use it but i can explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i find the solution using HttpPostedFileBase and Form Collection.

```
     public ActionResult AddImageUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files,FormCollection fc )
        {
            ImageUpload IU = new ImageUpload();
            IU.MaterialId = Convert.ToInt32((fc["MaterialId"]).Replace("number:",""));
            IU.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32((fc["CategoryId"]).Replace("number:", "")); 
            string tr = fc["hdnSub"].ToString();
            string result = null;
            string Message, fileName, actualFileName;
            Message = fileName = actualFileName = string.Empty;
            bool flag = false;
            //HttpPostedFileBase f= IU.ImageP;
            string[] SubAssemblyId = (tr.Split(','));
            int i = 0;
            string databaseid = null;
            for (int j=0 ; j<files.Count(); j++)
            {

                var fileContent = Request.Files[j];
                if (fileContent.FileName != "")
                {
                    databaseid = SubAssemblyId[i];
                    string fn = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "") + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Milliseconds + Path.GetExtension(fileContent.FileName);
                    fileName = fn;
                    try
                    {
                        if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            var inputStream = fileContent.InputStream;
                            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Images/Product/"), fn);
                            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                            {
                                inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                            }

                        }
 }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }

                }
                i++;

            }
return RedirectToAction("ImageUpload");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a sample code for the uploading of multiple image using angularjs.

This link might help you: https://jsfiddle.net/n9tL7cdr/1/

```
<div ng-app="test">
<div ng-controller="UploadCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
            <td>{{i}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)" />                           </td>
            <td>
                <img ng-src="{{ image[$index].dataUrl }}" height="50px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
angular.module('test', []);
angular.module('test').controller('UploadCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
// Variable for image. 
$scope.image = {
    dataUrl: []
};

$scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
$scope.photoChanged = function (files, index) {
    if (files != null) {
        var file = files[0];
        var index = this.$index; // index of image. 
        if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
            $timeout(function () {
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.image[index] = {dataUrl: e.target.result}; // Retrieve the image. 
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But how i can send my form data to asp.net controller with my images.

Comment: That would be your challenge. You should pass the data to the server with a multipart/form-data request. Read this link for more info: https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Comment: Thank you @Gracia I use HttpPostedFileBase for Images. And Form Collection for data passing.